# What is the purpose of desk.cpl?

Tags: windows

What is the purpose of Desk.cpl, when all the parts I see are in different files to this.

Control panel is explorer.exe
Display properties (title) is a shell32 string
The window is probably drawn from user32
The 5 tabs are in themeui and shell32.

I know that the cpl file is hosted by rundll32.exe and if it is deleted the display properties window will not appear at all, but I cannot work out what the purpose of the cpl file is.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the Microsoft Knowledge Base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/149648), a `.cpl` file is a tool in the Control Panel:

> Each tool in Control Panel is represented by a .cpl file in the Windows\ System folder. The .cpl files in the Windows\System folder are loaded automatically when you start Control Panel.
>
> ```
> File name      Purpose
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------
> Access.cpl     Accessibility properties
> Appwiz.cpl     Add/Remove Programs properties
> Desk.cpl       Display properties
> FindFast.cpl   FindFast (included with Microsoft Office for Windows 95)
> Inetcpl.cpl    Internet properties
> Intl.cpl       Regional Settings properties
> Joy.cpl        Joystick properties
> Main.cpl       Mouse, Fonts, Keyboard, and Printers properties
> Mlcfg32.cpl    Microsoft Exchange or Windows Messaging properties
> Mmsys.cpl      Multimedia properties
> Modem.cpl      Modem properties
> Netcpl.cpl     Network properties
> Odbccp32.cpl   Data Sources (32-bit ODBC, included w/ Microsoft Office)
> Password.cpl   Password properties
> Sticpl.cpl     Scanners and Cameras properties
> Sysdm.cpl      System properties and Add New Hardware wizard
> Themes.cpl     Desktop Themes 
> TimeDate.cpl   Date/Time properties
> Wgpocpl.cpl    Microsoft Mail Post Office
> ```

Comment: What Im not getting is what the tool does, what is this tool  if display properties is completley seperate.
On the other hand, access.cpl actually contains dialogs so it IS a tool

Comment: @user6457127 cpl stands for Control Panel appLet. It contains the information which Windows needs to display the window associated with it.

Comment: then why cant rundll just directly call the two dlls instead of calling the cpl file as well first. Desk,cpl only contains one dialog, but the dialog has been obsolete since windows NT 4.0, it contains nothing called 'Display Properties' which is why I am so confused. Explorer and shell32 and themeui also contain no information, What is also confusing is that the cpl file doesn't even need to be launched from control panel, it can be launched by right clicking the desktop and clicking properties, clicking the CPL file manually, or by some command line command

Comment: Your asking questions we can't possible answer.

Comment: I know that the function to open it is Control_RunDLL because of this path: "rundll32.exe" shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL "C:\WINDOWS\system32\desk.cpl", even if explorer is not running  Control.exe does not run unless you type control.exe rundll32.dll desk.cpl

Comment: I used wingrep again but searched for "Display" instead of "Display Properties" and now I know that the title of display properties is located in desk.cpl. but the 5 tabs are named in shell32 (1) and themeui (4). So I think I have comprehended it now, Im not sure where the actual dialog is coming from, probably user32 but who knows. I also don't know where the 'Properties' part of the dialog title is coming from.

Comment: @user6457127 I'll need to look into it